# Converting Binary to INT in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have an obsolete 4GL application, which keeps IDs as binary without any encryption.
I have tried simple CAST AS INT, CAST (SUBSTRING(..,3,1000) AS INT) and so to no avail. Can one advise, please?

In the example below binary_source column is a sample data from SQL Server, correct_result one - the result, presented in 4GL application and in between - some of my attempts to convert.

```
WITH binary_to_convert AS
(
SELECT 0x1841506A00000000 AS binary_source,100005 AS correct_result
UNION ALL SELECT 0x1841506A00000000,100005
UNION ALL SELECT 0x1841506A00000000,100005
UNION ALL SELECT 0x1841506A00000000,100005
UNION ALL SELECT 0x1841506A00000000,100005
UNION ALL SELECT 0x1841706A00000000,100007
UNION ALL SELECT 0x1841706A00000000,100007
UNION ALL SELECT 0x1841906A00000000,100009
UNION ALL SELECT 0x1841906A00000000,100009
UNION ALL SELECT 0x1841706A00000000,100007
UNION ALL SELECT 0x1841706A00000000,100007
UNION ALL SELECT 0x1841706A00000000,100007
UNION ALL SELECT 0x1841706A00000000,100007
UNION ALL SELECT 0x1841706A00000000,100007)

SELECT b.binary_source,
        cast(b.binary_source AS INT) AS INT_COLUMN,
  CAST(SUBSTRING(b.binary_source,3,1000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS VARCHAR_COLUMN,
  CAST(SUBSTRING(b.binary_source,3,1000) AS INT) AS INT_CAST_COLUMN,
        b.correct_result
 FROM binary_to_convert b
```

Comment: Does the correct result column contain the expected result?

Comment: yes it is. Thank you for the comment

Comment: Too little range of examples. We only really have 3 samples here, and all of them *could* be obtained by appending the 5th hex digit in the binary (but treated as decimal) to the end of `10000`. But obviously that completely ignores the rest of the binary data.

Comment: `100005` is `0186A5`, which does not resemble `1841506A00000000`. There's definitely a correlation between the input and the output, but the storage does not appear to be a simple two's complement binary. (Nor is it IEEE floating point.) Are these the only three values you're required to support? If so, a simple `CASE` would help you. If not, I'd dig deeper into the recesses of what the 4GL system uses for its storage format -- guessing could take a while, and be unreliable.

Comment: Get the application owners to tell you how they got `0x1841506A00000000` from `100005`. You're going to need that inside info to reliably do the reverse.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever if it helps:
0xD34170AB00220000 is 330002466. Will obtain a bit more shortly.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thank you for the comment. The product is obsolete due to a reason, hence cannot ask the owners as per your suggestion.

Comment: At this point, get as many examples as possible. Convert the `int` expected values to binary. Then, identify correlations at the bit level. It looks like there may be correlations at the nibble level too, so you could try that first. If there is correlation here, it appears quite scrambled in places.

Comment: If there's still a toolchain around, consider writing code in the 4GL system itself to convert all existing rows (at least in terms of producing a mapping file that you can process elsewhere). Of course, if you only have binaries and no compiler it gets more complicated. If the system is not entirely custom, built from scratch (which would make it *very* old indeed :-)), try identifying the language/framework/library/dinosaur mainframe it uses -- it seems probable that it's not the only system storing values like this, and someone will know what's what.

Comment: It would help to see some *special* values, if you can get them: 0, 1, -1, 1024, 2048. Or - if this is possible for your: What are the int-values for 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000, 0xFF00FF00FF00FF00, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000000000000F ...

Comment: As it says @Damien_The_Unbeliever we have only three samples (100005,100007,100009) and we can achieve the value by replacing the first five decimals, keeping the sixth and eliminating the rest). for this you can use the following substring function.


SELECT 
    '0x1841506A00000000' AS [original_value], 
    '10000' + SUBSTRING('0x1841506A00000000',7,1) AS [substring_value]
I'm not sure if the conversion to whole, get the desired number.

Comment: Are you sure the binary is only encoding the id? Given then pattern youv'e found (part of the binary seems to encode part of the id), perhaps other parts of the binary value contain data from other columns.

Comment: @allmhuran I am sure - there is a simple browsing program, which shows the content of the table, e.g. it shows binary ID column in question, Abbriviation, Name and Description. Same columns exist in SQL and all have the same values, except the binary ID column. which I am yet able to convert.